# Using LINQ how to select from a List within a List

Tags: c#, linq

```
public class StandardTrackingOutput
{
    public string MainCommitee { get; set; }
    public List<SubCommittees> SubCommittees { get; set; }
}

public class SubCommittees
{
    public string FormattedCommittee { get; set; }
    public string CommitteeTitle { get; set; }
}
```

I want to generate StandardTrackingOutput from list having columns MainCommittee, FormattedCommittee and    CommitteeTitle on behalf of MainCommittee.

And i have following data: [enter image description here][1]

**MainCommittee    FormattedCommittee  CommitteeTitle
ABC               ABC                 Data1
ABC               ABC.01              Data2
ABC               ABC.02              Data3
ABC               ABC.03              Data4
XYZ               XYZ                 Data20
XYZ               XYZ.09              Data16
XYZ               XYZ.08              Data5**

i want to return list of StandardTrackingOutput

Thanks in advance for help

Comment: And why can't you?

Comment: this isn't a codewriting service. try yourself first, ask specifically what doesn't work

Comment: What do you mean with `of list`? So what is the source you want to convert to `List<StandardTrackingOutput>` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you are doing a GroupBy:

```
void Main()
{
    var myData = new List<MyData> {
        new MyData{ MainCommitee="ABC", FormattedCommittee="ABC", CommitteeTitle="Data1" },
        new MyData{ MainCommitee="ABC", FormattedCommittee="ABC.01", CommitteeTitle="Data2" },
        new MyData{ MainCommitee="ABC", FormattedCommittee="ABC.02", CommitteeTitle="Data3" },
        new MyData{ MainCommitee="ABC", FormattedCommittee="ABC.03", CommitteeTitle="Data4" },
        new MyData{ MainCommitee="XYZ", FormattedCommittee="XYZ", CommitteeTitle="Data20" },
        new MyData{ MainCommitee="XYZ", FormattedCommittee="XYZ.09", CommitteeTitle="Data16" },
        new MyData{ MainCommitee="XYZ", FormattedCommittee="XYZ.08", CommitteeTitle="Data5" },
    };
    var result = myData.GroupBy(d => d.MainCommitee)
        .Select(d => new StandardTrackingOutput
        {
            MainCommitee = d.Key,
            SubCommittees = d.Select(s =>
                new SubCommittees
                {
                    FormattedCommittee = s.FormattedCommittee,
                    CommitteeTitle = s.CommitteeTitle
                })
                .ToList()
        });
    // if you have LinqPad (why not)
    // result.Dump(); 
}

public class StandardTrackingOutput
{
    public string MainCommitee { get; set; }
    public List<SubCommittees> SubCommittees { get; set; }
}

public class SubCommittees
{
    public string FormattedCommittee { get; set; }
    public string CommitteeTitle { get; set; }
}

public class MyData
{
    public string MainCommitee { get; set; }
    public string FormattedCommittee { get; set; }
    public string CommitteeTitle { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should [`groupBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netcore-3.1) `MainCommitee` and build the expected result :

```
List<StandardTrackingOutput> result = committees
    .GroupBy(x => x.MainCommitee)
    .Select(x => new StandardTrackingOutput
    {
        MainCommitee = x.Key,
        SubCommittees = x.Select(y => new SubCommittees
        {
            CommitteeTitle = y.CommitteeTitle,
            FormattedCommittee = y.FormattedCommittee
        }).ToList()
    })
    .ToList();
```